# Change of basis-linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

I see there are other change of basis posts, but it seems like they are not asking the same question as me, or perhaps my understanding is so poor, I do not understand they are asking the same questions.

Linear algebra was going so well until this concept, which I cannot wrap my head around. I honestly need someone to work through this practice problem( not for a grade) to explain how to solve it. There is an example in my book, but for some reason when I solve it as they do, I do not get the answer...

Part a is not the problem, it is part b

**Instructions**: In Exercises 37–42, find T(x) by using (a) the standard matrix and (b) the matrix relative to $B$ and $B'$.

$T: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3, T(x, y, z) = (x + y +z, 2z- x, 2y-z)$

$v = (4, -5, 10)$

$B = \{(2, 0, 1), (0, 2, 1), (1, 2, 1)\}$

$B' = \{(1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1)\}$

$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1\\-1&0&2\\0&2&-1\end{pmatrix}$

$P=\begin{pmatrix}2&0&1\\0&2&2\\1&1&1\end{pmatrix}$

$Q^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}1&-1&1\\0&1&-1\\-1&1&0\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! The bases $B$ and $B'$ are for the domain and the codomain respectively?

Comment: Yes they are, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the change of base posts are basically the same.  The key is that any invertible matrix can be interpreted as the change of basis matrix from the standard basis to the basis consisting of its columns.

The standard matrix for $T$ is found by applying it to the standard basis vectors:  $T(1,0,0)=(1,-1,0),T(0,1,0)=(1,0,2)$ and $T(0,0,1)=(1,2,-1)$.  Thus we get $\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1\\-1&0&2\\0&2&-1\end{pmatrix}$.

The matrix rel $B$ and $B'$ is gotten by multiplying the matrix in the standard basis by $P=\begin{pmatrix}2&0&1\\0&2&2\\1&1&1\end{pmatrix}$ on the right and the matrix $Q^{-1}$ on the left, where $Q=\begin{pmatrix}1&1&0\\1&1&1\\1&0&1\end{pmatrix}$.

(Notice the columns of $P$ and $Q$ are the elements of $B$ and $B'$ respectively.)

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and did not get the correct answer. The answer is (9,16,-20). I get PTQ-1={(5,8,6),(5,8,5),(-2,-2,-1)}, and an answer of (-25,-28,11)

Comment: I indicated $Q^{-1}TP$.

Comment: I then get an answer of (30,7,-1), which is also not correct...

Comment: I also get $(30,7,-1)$.

Comment: So, I checked it by hand and the answer we are getting is correct.  The answer you have is wrong.

Comment: Do you see how to check it?  In the basis $B$, we have that $(4,-5,10)$ is $(18,10,9)$.  Then apply $T$, and write the result in terms of $B'$.

Comment: (-25,-28,11) is incorrect? Its what is in the back of the book. I have been getting different answers than the back of the book for all these problem...maybe the book being wrong is the root of all the confusion?

Comment: Maybe.  Either that or we have an interpretation problem.  I am trying to guess what else the author might have meant.  But coming up empty.

Comment: Sorry the answer is (9,16,-20) not (-25,-28,11). The answer is supposed to be the same for a and b. Sorry that was probably my fault for the confusion

Comment: How is $(9,16,-20)$ the answer to $(a)$?

Comment: Sorry, that is my mistake again, I added plus signs where there should be minus signs in the matrix A. I was trying to copy directly from the book in order not to make errors, but I think I ended up making more errors that way

Comment: Okay.  Now you need to change $A$.  This could explain the discrepancy.

Comment: Now I get (48,-11,-37)

Comment: Well, the answer to $a$ is $(9,16,0)$.  So for $b$ we should get $Q^{-1}$ applied to that .  Which is $(-7,16,7)$.  One or both of us are still making careless mistakes.

Comment: I double checked everything to make sure it is copied over correctly. I think the answer to a) should be (9,16,-20) though. Q-1v=(-27,36,7)

Comment: Sorry, this one was me again.  It's $(9,16,-20)$ as you said.  So we should get $(-27,36,7)$ for $b$.

Comment: I think this is correct.  The answers agree, up to change of basis.

Comment: Okay thanks! I think I have the general understanding how to go about these problem

Answer (score 0):

Let $A$ be the matrix of $T$ in the standard basis.

If we denote $X'$ the column matrix of a vector in the domain and if $P$ is the change of basis matrix from the standard basis to basis $\mathcal B$, we have the relation $$X=PX'.$$
Similarly, if   $X'$ denotes the column matrix of a vector in the codomain and if $Q$ is the change of basis matrix from the standard basis to basis $\mathcal B'$, we have the relation $$Y=QY'.$$

Therefire the relation $Y=AX$ becomes
$$QY'=A(PX')\iff Y'=(Q^{-1}AP)X',$$
and as a consequence, the matrix of $T$ relative to bases $\mathcal B$ and $\mathcal B'$ is
$\:\color{red}{Q^{-1}AP}$.

Comment: Thanks, although I am still confused. In this, is the vector, v, X? My understanding is the question in asking me to find Y', but I need to find q first, which i dont understand how to do

Comment: $X$ is the column matrix of the coordinates of v in the standard basis. As to $Q$, the change of basis matrix from the standard basis to the basis  $\mathcal B'$, its columns are the coordinates of the vectors in $\mathcal B'$ w.r.t. the standard basis. Is that clearer?

Comment: Yes, that is what Chris did below, however I do not get the correct answer when doing this, I get (30,7,-1), when the answer is (-25,-28,11)

Comment: Could you post what you used for $A, P, Q$ and $Q^{-1}$?

Comment: I have posted what AP and Q-1 are

Comment: These are the same I obtain.